# Do I still need to have a virtual destructor for my derived class in this situation?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I have been reading Effective C++ 3rd Edition by Scott Meyers and in one of the chapters he says that any class with virtual functions should almost certainly have a virtual destructor. Now for my code below, the function `someFunc` does not need a virtual in the derived class. However, I decided to put it there to show semantics and for better readability. Since I put the virtual there, does it mean that the destructor in the derived class has to be virtual?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{

public:
    base(){...}
    virtual ~base(){...}

    virtual someFunc() = 0;

};

class derived1:public base
{

public:
    derived1(){...} 
    ~derived1(){...} //Does this need to be virtual?

    virtual someFunc(/*Implement the function*/); //I made this virtual just to show meaning

};

int main()
{

    base* b;
    b=new derived1;
    delete b; //Will this cause a memory leak?

}
```

Comment: The destructor is already virtual. You may add a `virtual` keyword for readability but it doesn't change the semantics fo the code. I'm looking for a good duplicate.

Comment: N.B. there is a difference between a function being virtual, and you writing the `virtual` keyword. I think you have a misunderstanding here. Hopefully my answer clarifies it a little.

Comment: As soon as a function (destructor) is marked virtual it stays virtual in all derived classes. The repetition of 'virtual' was a nice hint before C++ 11. Now you should use override, when overriding a  virtual function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It already is!**

The `virtual` keyword is implicit for your `derived::someFunc`, and for your `derived::~derived`, because both functions' base equivalents are marked `virtual`.

So, you may write the keyword `virtual` on both, neither or just one. It doesn't matter: they will both be actually virtual regardless.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, you still need a *virtual destructor for the derived* class.

**But no**, you don't need to use `virtual` on it, nor declare it at all:
The base-class-version being virtual automatically makes the derived one virtual without you having to do anything.

Comment: So even if the virtual destructor of a derived class does not do anything I need to add it in order to avoid undefined behavior?

Comment: If the dtor is not explicitly declared, it is implicitly defined. You only have to bother if you need custom behavior. Either way, if any parent is virtual, it will be too.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's a virtual before the parent destructor it automatically calls the destructor in children's class when you delete the allocated memory , you don't have to put virtual in children's destructor .